# Parameters of POST request to Java server from Angular client

Tags: java, angularjs, arrays, post

I've got Angular app and Java server.

I need to send POST request with JSON object consisting of string array and string field.

I'm using Angularjs $resource and Java javax.ws.rs.

My latest try as follows:

**Client:**

```
    var messages = $resource('resources/messages/getmessages', {}, {
        update: { method: 'POST', url: 'resources/messages/updatemessages' }
    });
    //...
    var _args = {   'msgIdList': ['1', '2', '3'],
                    'action': 'makeSmth'   };

    return messages.update(_args).$promise.then(
        function (data) {
            //...
        },
        function (error) {
            //...
        }
    )
```

**Server:**

```
    @POST   
    @Path("updatemessages")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON +"; charset=UTF-8")
    public Response updateMessages( @FormParam("msgIdList") List<String> msgIdList,
                                    @DefaultValue("") @FormParam("action") String action,
                                    @CookieParam("rgsid") String c_sid, 
                                    @Context HttpServletRequest httpservletreq) {
//...
}
```

The problem is that I've got ***415*** Unsupported Media Type error, and don't know what to do next. I've tried lots of things, but may be I was wrong from the start, and I can't pass parameters this way?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, eventually I made a wrapper class, so now it looks this way:

```
@XmlRootElement
private static class RequestWrapper {
    @XmlElement
    private ArrayList<String> msgIdList;
    @XmlElement
    private String action;

    public ArrayList<String> getMsgIdList() {
        return msgIdList;
    }
    public void setMsgIdList(ArrayList<String> msgIdList) {
        this.msgIdList = msgIdList;
    }
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }
    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    } 
    public RequestWrapper() {

    }
}

@POST   
@Path("updatemessages")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON +"; charset=UTF-8")
public Response updateMessages( RequestWrapper requestData,
                                @CookieParam("rgsid") String c_sid, 
                                @Context HttpServletRequest httpservletreq) {
//...}
```

Angular part stays unchanged.
I'm not really sure, if this the right way to go (class description and so on), but it works.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this in your angular, maybe it can help.

```
            var sendPost = $http({
                method: "post",
                url:"JAVA_SERVER_SERVICE_URL",
                data: {
                    msgIdList: 'your_value',
                    action: 'your_value'
                },
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this, unfortunately there was still 415 error. I tried another way, with creating wrapper class in java.